# Exclude file which not contains string in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here is my folder structure:

```
lang
|_ translate_en.js
|_ translate_cs.js
|_ translate_de.js
```

I want to exclude all the files except the `en` file.

I tried something like this:

```js
"search.exclude": {
  // this hide all the files "lang/translate_*.js": true 
  "lang/translate_!(en).js": true
  // or "lang/translate_*!(en).js": true 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```json
"search.exclude": {
    "lang": false,
    "lang/.*": true,
    "lang/language_[abcdfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz][abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz]*": true,
    "lang/language_e[abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz]*": true,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have another file in that folder `translate_es` and somehow it still shows up in the search result.

Comment: I don't even know this works) [some article](http://maxisam.github.io/2016/12/09/how-to-do-negative-pattern-for-VS-code-files-exclude/). If you figure it out then feel free to edit my answer. For now you can add another rule specifically for es.

Comment: "lang/translate_es.js": true,

Comment: Thanks! But I think we don't need the 2 first lines.